# Why won't Laravel let me create a new application?

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to create a new application and I do 'Laravel new app_name' I get this:

> 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I'm also using Windows 10 with a command prompt. I even tried it with PowerShell, but no hope.

Comment: Try the alternate installation method. `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app_name`

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/laravel/installer/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

`rm` command is only in unix system

Try to install laravel via composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {app_name} --prefer-dist
```